# How to pass generic type to a generic method that is from class?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

suppose that I have a class, and I want an alias type for foo.

```
class A {
  foo<T>() {}
}

// How to I pass "T"? TS could not parse  "A['foo']<T>" or " <T>A['foo']"
type FooType<T> = A['foo']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function foo<Type>(arg: Type): Type {}
```

to call:

```
foo<string>();
```